# material components in navigation in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, tabbar, material-components-ios

how to use material components tab bar to change the view controller

and embed all viewcontrollers in one single tab view item

(i want nested tab view one at top and one at bottom)

what i need is at this image [image]

Comment: What efforts you have done so far?

Comment: i finished the bottom bar and draw the top bar but cannot navigate 
as i need

Comment: @PPL Any help ?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using `MDCTabBarViewController`?

With it you can provide view controllers by instantiating them and providing them to its `viewControllers` property. You can also set the `selectedViewController` to provide the view controller that is initially presented. The `MDCTabBarViewController` has a `tabBar` property where you can customize the `MDCTabBar` to your needs.

Have a look at this example if you need more implementation guidance: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/blob/develop/components/Tabs/examples/TabBarViewControllerExample.m